# Failed to access remote file: access denied. Please check your credentials in loading data into snowflake from aws s3 bucket file - SSE S3 encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I am trying to load a simple CSV file from s3 to snowflake using aws external stage. I am able to list the files using list @stage_name command but get the access denied error while loading the file via copy into sql. I checked the encryption which is default SSE S3 for the file and as per snowflake documentation [snowflake_document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-encrypt) no additional encryption setting is required for SSE S3 type of encryption.
Below is the command copy command i am using

```
list @my_ext_stage_2;
```

[image]

```
copy into emp_raw from @my_ext_stage_2/emp/emp.csv
on_error='ABORT_STATEMENT';
```

[image]

```
desc stage my_ext_stage_2;
```

[image]

my access policy in aws is below

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*Object",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: was this csv file uploaded to s3 by the same aws account who owns the S3 bucket or it was uploaded from somewhere else?

Comment: yes , uploaded the fille manually using the same user.... I am accessing the bucket with aws key id and secret of a role which has access to s3 bucket via above policy @aek

Comment: Can you update your question with the full COPY INTO command you are running (obviously obfuscate any sensitive information). I assume you are running the COPY INTO using the same user/role you are using to run the LIST command?

Comment: @NickW i have updated the details you asked. I am using the same role for listing the stage and loading the file.

Comment: Can you query the data in the stage i.e. run something like: SELECT t.$1 FROM @my_ext_stage_2 t; ? Also, you access policy doesn't match either of the examples in the Snowflake policy (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration) so that may be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake requires the following permissions on an S3 bucket and folder to be able to access files in the folder (and sub-folders):

```
s3:GetBucketLocation
s3:GetObject
s3:GetObjectVersion
s3:ListBucket
```

As part of your policy the `s3:*Object` action uses a wildcard as part of the action name. The `AllObjectActions` statement allows the `GetObject`, `DeleteObject`, `PutObject`, and any other Amazon S3 action that ends with the word `"Object"`. This means for example that `s3:GetBucketLocation` is not allowed, therefore an example of a read-only policy should look like this example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/<prefix>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "<prefix>/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration).

Comment: above mentioned permission set also worked. Thanks @Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

as expected the issues was with the policy permissions only. Some other permissions than *object and listBucket were required.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sf-inbounds"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::sf-inbounds",
            "arn:aws:s3:::sf-inbounds/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I was able to load data from a file into snowflake table and unload into s3 directory from table as well.